# In excel is it possible to create a list of unique values from a column and copy data from another column with it?

Tags: excel

I have a list of data in Column B which sometimes has repeated items. In column A there is an identifier for each item. I would like to create a list that only shows 1 instance of each item and the identifier with it.

Here is a screenshot of the list i have and the expected output:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ITEM ID column is always a number, I would suggest using `MINIFS`.

You can select the lowest ID, which is greater than any you have already selected:

```
 MINIFS($A$3:$A$17,$A$3:$A$17,">" & MAX($E$2:$E2))
```

If there are no more unique IDs left, it will return 0. So we can add a check for this and get it to return an empty string instead:

```
=IF(MINIFS($A$3:$A$17,$A$3:$A$17,">" & MAX($E$2:$E2))=0,"",MINIFS($A$3:$A$17,$A$3:$A$17,">" & MAX($E$2:$E2)))
```

Then to get the names from this ID, I strongly dislike `VLOOKUP`. In my opinion, this formula should NEVER be used. An INDEX/MATCH formula is better in every way. It is faster, more reliable (as inserting columns does not break it), easier to use(as you don't need to count columns), more versatile (your ranges don't have to be inline with each other).

The INDEX/MATCH to use, would be:

```
INDEX($B$3:$B$17,MATCH($E3,$A$3:$A$17,0))
```

You can then wrap this in an IF, to return an empty string when there are no IDs left:

```
=IF($E3="","",INDEX($B$3:$B$17,MATCH($E3,$A$3:$A$17,0)))
```

Please see this image for illustration:

[image]

**EDIT: How to create a sequential Numeric ID from text IDs**

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A2)>0,
    INDEX($B$1:$B1,MATCH($A2,$A$1:$A1,0)),
    MAX($B$1:$B1)+1
)
```

What this formula does, is check to see if that string value has already been assigned an ID. If it has, it retrieves that ID with INDEX/MATCH. If it hasn't, it assigns it the next number in the sequence by taking the maximum numeric ID previously assigned and adding 1.

If you want to ignore blank text IDs, just wrap it in an IF to return a blank:

```
=IF($A2="","",<Formula Above>)
```

Comment: In that case you could create a numeric ID column which uses the String ID. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that normally in this cases I use Pivot Tables. I'm a lazy guy, and unless this process is part of a macro or any kind of daily and heavy procedure/subroutine, I use Pivot Tables, because it works with ID's being numbers or strings.

Let's say you got this:

[image]

Create a Pivot Table, and just take both fields to *Rows* section. Make sure you deactivate subtotals, and apply a **[tabular design](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80)**

You will get this:

[image]

It takes around... 25 seconds to make it. No complex formulas. But as I said, this solution may not work for everyone.

But I love it. More info about Pivot Tables:

> **[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**

Comment: Pivot tables are great if you want a quick analysis of the data. Unfortunately, as soon as you want to do anything more complicated, it tends to become problematic/impossible. Hence, I would rather create the pivots manually, using my own formulas, in order to have more control over them.

Answer (score 0):

For IDs use:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$17,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$3:E3,$A$3:$A$17),0))
```

Put it in `E4` and drag it, once you hit `#N/A` all unique values are listed.

Then you can use `VLOOKUP` for names:

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,$A$3:$B$17,2,0)
```